# CakePHP blackholing search after using back button

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm having a problem with SecurityComponent in my CakePHP 2.4 app:

I have a form which is hooked up to the CakeDC Search plugin to filter the results on my `index` action. The problem is that SecurityComponent does exactly what it's supposed to do, and protects against a form being submitted twice- if a user searches, goes back, and searches again, it throws a CSRF error because the token has already been used.

I've tried one solution for this, which involves disabling SecurityComponent on my `index` action with this code in `beforeFilter`:

```
if($this->request->action == 'index'){
     $this->Components->disable('Security');
  }
```

This protects users against a blackhole error, however it also means that my delete links no longer work because the `delete` action expects a token from a page with Security enabled- and for obvious reasons I don't want to disable Security on `delete.`

How can I avoid blackholes when users search after using the back button, while still keeping SecurityComponent running so my delete links work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read the documentation about CSRF.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#csrf-configuration)

> SecurityComponent::$csrfUseOnce Controls whether or not CSRF tokens
>   are single use. Set to false to not generate new tokens on each
>   request. One token will be reused until it expires. This reduces the
>   chances of users getting invalid requests because of token
>   consumption. It has the side effect of making CSRF less secure, as
>   tokens are reusable.

Re-using the token should solve the problem.